# sed out string middle of string that may contain one or more numbers

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

My strings are:

- "TESTING_ABC_1-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1"
- "TESTING_ABC_30-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1"

In bash when I run:
`echo "TESTING_ABC_1-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1" | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,2\}-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'`  it returns 1-JAN-2022 which is good.

But when I run:
`echo "TESTING_ABC_30-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1" | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,2\}-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'` I get 0-JAN-2022 but I want 30-JAN-2022.

From me passing in my string. How can I do it so that I can get single or double digit dates in one line like "30-JAN-2022" or "1-JAN-2022"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to use `awk` and avoid any regex:

```bash
cat file

TESTING_ABC_1-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1
TESTING_ABC_30-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1

awk -F '[_.]' '{print $3}' file

1-JAN-2022
30-JAN-2022
```

Another option is to use `grep -Eo` with a valid regex for date in `DD-MON-YYYY` format:

```bash
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}' file

1-JAN-2022
30-JAN-2022
```

Comment: I realized later on there were also only numbers in only a few files so the grepped worked the best in my case.

Answer (score 4):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Simply using `gsub` function of `awk` to globally substitute from starting of value to till 2nd occurrence of `-` AND from dot to till last of value with NULL and printing remaining of the value of current line.

```
awk '{gsub(/^[^_]*_[^_]*_|\..*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following code. Using `-oP` options to print matched value and enabling PCRE regex with these options respectively. In main program using `.*?` concept for non-greedy match and using it 2 times from starting of value to match till 2nd occurrence of `_` and then using `\K` option to forget all matched values. After that matching values just before `.` occurrence to get required output.

```
grep -oP '^(.*?_){2}\K[^.]*' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `awk` with its `match` function which is using array concept of creating its indexes(keys) from matched regex's capturing groups.

```
awk 'match($0,/^[^_]*_[^_]*_([^.]*)/,arr){print arr[1]}' Input_file
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** Using `sed` with `-E` option to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) and using regex `^[^_]*_[^_]*_([^.]*).*` to create 1 and only capturing group which contains required value in it and using substitute function to substitute whole value with only captured value.

```
sed -E 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_([^.]*).*/\1/' Input_file
```

---

---

***5th solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following, thanks to "the fourth bird" for this one.

```
grep -oP '^(?:[^_]*_){2}\K[^.]*' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo "TESTING_ABC_1-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1
> TESTING_ABC_30-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1" | sed -E 's/[^0-9]*([^.]*).*/\1/'
1-JAN-2022
30-JAN-2022
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your regex is that greedy `*` quantifier: `.*` will match as many characters as possible while still being able to match the rest of your input. In many regex implementations you can change the greedyness of `*` by adding `?`. So `/.*?a/` would match as few characters as possible until it finds an `a`.
Unfortunately, sed doesn't support changing greedyness. Here are two options:

If your string always has an `_` before the date, you can simply add `_` to that `.*` part:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}).*/\1/' <<< "TESTING_ABC_30-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1"
30-JAN-2022
```

Or just grep the relevant part:

```
$ grep -Po '[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}' <<< "TESTING_ABC_30-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1"
30-JAN-2022
```

Answer (score 1):

if u wanna do it in the most arbitrarily hard-coded-in fashion, try :

> ```
> echo 'TESTING_ABC_1-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1
>       TESTING_ABC_30-JAN-2022.BCK-gz;1' | 
>
> {m,g}awk ++NF OFS= FS='.+_|[.].+$' 
>
> gawk -F'.+_|[.].+$' '$_=$--NF' # only if u know for certain 
>                                # there aren't empty lines in btwn
> ```

```
1-JAN-2022
30-JAN-2022
```